# I get this error when i start server.js on nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I get this error when i start server.js on nodejs

`D:\NodeJS\CloudFlux\FLamer\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\lib\server .js:228         process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })                                             ^ Error     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NodeJS\CloudFlux\FLamer\node_modules\mongoose\node _modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:42:24)     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)     at Module.load (module.js:355:32)     at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)     at Module.require (module.js:365:17)     at require (module.js:384:17)     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\NodeJS\CloudFlux\FLamer\node_modules\mongoose\node _modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\index.js:2:17)     at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)`

Comment: Well, it has to do with mongoose, but the error could literally be anything.

Comment: update mongodb and mongoose to latest version